# How to generate a random treatment variable by factor?

Tags: r, random, r-factor

Define

```
x <- data.frame(
     ID=letters[1:10],
     class = as.factor(c(rep(1,5),rep(2,5))),
     treat = rep(0,10))
```

s.t.

```
> x
   ID class treat
1   a     1     0
2   b     1     0
3   c     1     0
4   d     1     0
5   e     1     0
6   f     2     0
7   g     2     0
8   h     2     0
9   i     2     0
10  j     2     0
```

I have a treatment with two levels, 1 & 2.  I want to assign exactly one one unit per class to each level s.t. that, after randomization, we get something like:

```
> x
   ID class treat
1   a     1     0
2   b     1     0
3   c     1     1
4   d     1     0
5   e     1     2
6   f     2     0
7   g     2     0
8   h     2     0
9   i     2     2
10  j     2     1
```

s.t. units *c* and *j* get level 1 of treatment and *e* and *i* level 2.

How do I generate the treatment vector in R?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll assume you just want to assign *one* level 1 treatment and *one* level 2 treatment in each class. You can use the `ddply` function from the `plyr` package to do it easily:

```
  set.seed(1)
  require(plyr)
> ddply(x, .(class), transform, 
        treat = replace(treat, sample(seq_along(treat),2), 1:2))

   ID class treat
1   a     1     0
2   b     1     1
3   c     1     0
4   d     1     0
5   e     1     2
6   f     2     0
7   g     2     0
8   h     2     1
9   i     2     2
10  j     2     0
```

To explain: the `ddply` function splits the data-frame by the `class` variable, and within each data-frame, it "`transforms`" the `treat` column by replacing 2 randomly chosen entries by 1 and 2. The `sample(...,2)` function picks two random indices in the `treat` column. Other variants (e.g. assign more than 1 of each treatment type) can be done similarly.

Comment: Many thanks!  This is exactly what I wanted.  Made small changes to question to make it clearer as per your comments.